# What criteria was used by the Community user to delete this question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Referring to: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/236367/40609

Does anyone know what the current criteria is for the Community user to automatically delete a question?

I looked [at this criteria list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) that can be accessed via the [Community user page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), and [this criteria list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), which is apparently the official FAQ for automated deletions, but none of the criteria apply to the question linked above.

Comment: Migrated here since moderators can better clarify what happened here. From the Wayback Machine I can already see the OP's account has been deleted. The question has not been [roomba'd](/help/roomba)...

Comment: Next time, you can determine the reason for a Community user deletion by going to the post timeline, the button underneath the voting mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer wasn't deleted because of its own merit, rather it has been an unfortunate collateral damage.

The user who posted the question was destroyed, and with the user all of their posts were gone, too, pulling with them the existing answers, including yours.

Comment: I wasn't worried about my answer. The headers are clear that it's hidden because the question was deleted. What I didn't understand was the criteria behind Community deleting the question. I freely admit that I didn't consider the possibility of the account having been deleted.